# Issues with HotKey plugin under keydown event

Tags: jquery, html

I used hotkeys.js plugin for keydown event.Then Event is called when i only press `ctrl` and it calls the last function. Please help me out.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="hotkeys.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+h', function() {
            window.location.replace("home.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+i', function() {
            window.location.replace("add item.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+m', function() {
            window.location.replace("add make.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+q', function() {
            window.location.replace("add sales.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+z', function() {
            window.location.replace("add purchase.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', function() {
            window.location.replace("add account.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+b', function() {
            window.location.replace("add user.php");
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+x', function() {  
            window.location.replace("add department.php");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the hotkeys plugin I used: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

I simply want a keyboard shortcuts to navigate to pages in my project.

Comment: Please don't include an entire plugin in your question. It just wastes space and bandwidth. A link to the plugin is more than sufficient.